# Playback a video file to Skype to simulate a webcam

Tags: windows, software-rec, skype, webcam

Is there any software that allows me to simulate a webcam and playback video files to another party on Skype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com/) can use an video feed or image which can then be viewed by MSN/Windows Live Messenger and Skype. Windows/Mac, Freeware.

[How to remove ManyCam watermark](http://blog.manycam.com/?p=6) - link to ManyCam Blog.